# Нехолодный-негорячий / ни холодный, ни горячий чаёк — это тёплый чай

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Нехолодный-негорячий чаёк — это тёплый чай.

> Ни холодный, ни горячий чаёк — это тёплый чай.